# Toggle Class to only one button in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular4-forms

I have two buttons I want to toggle class to the currently clicked button. The condition is user only select one button at a time and the user can also deselect both buttons. Here is my code [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7nzud). I have toggle class but now I am facing problem to deselect selected button. Please help.

Comment: what's the pont of doing this actually?

Comment: I want this kind of functionality for one of my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons" class="btn rounded m-4" [ngClass]="(selectedButton == button) ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default'" (click)="onClickButton(button)">
 <i [class]="button.class"></i>
</button>
```

**TS**

```
onClickButton(button): void {
 if (this.selectedButton === button) {
  this.selectedButton = null;
 } else {
 this.selectedButton = button;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the state of the buttons somewhere, I will do it in the buttons array:

```
[
  {class: "fa fa-long-arrow-up", name: "button1", selected: false},
  {class: "fa fa-long-arrow-down", name: "button2", selected: false},
]
```

We need to identify buttons with ids. See `*ngFor`. And call a function on click to do the logic behind it.
Template:

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index" class="btn rounded m-4" [ngClass]="button.selected ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default'" (click)="selectButton(i)">
    <i [class]="button.class"></i>
</button>
```

We invert the state of the clicked button. And toggle all other buttons off.
TS:

```
 public selectButton(j: number){
   this.buttons[j].selected = !this.buttons[j].selected;
   for(let i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; i++){
    if(i != j){
      this.buttons[i].selected = false;
    }
   }
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-powyop?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

**AppComponent**

```
<import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  buttons= [
  {class: "fa fa-long-arrow-up", name: "button1"},
  {class: "fa fa-long-arrow-down", name: "button2"},
]
  selectedButton;

  buttonNum:number;

  clickButton(event,i){
    if(this.buttonNum == i){
      this.buttonNum = -1;
    }else{
      this.buttonNum = i;
    }
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons; let i = index" class="btn rounded m-4" [ngClass]="(i == buttonNum) ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default'" (click)="clickButton($event,i)">
    <i [class]="button.class"></i>
</button>
```